# orientation detection in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, orientation, ios6, uistoryboard

This is in my AppDelegate, and runs on orientation change. When the application loads it ALWAYS loads as portrait mode. If I load the application while the device is in landscape mode this still executes as if the device was in portrait mode. Thats the first problem I have. The second is that after load when I rotate the device from portrait to landscape I get a thread break as notated below:

```
-(void)setOrientationView
{

    UIDevice *currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [currentDevice endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    UIDeviceOrientation theOr = currentDevice.orientation;

    if ( UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(theOr) && !isLandVisible )
    {
        NSLog(@"setLand");
        isLandVisible = YES;
        isPortVisible = NO;

        [self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:portCont animated:YES];   // <Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1

    }

    if( UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(theOr) && !isPortVisible )
    {
        NSLog(@"setPort");
        isPortVisible = YES;
        isLandVisible = NO;

        [self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:portCont animated:YES];

    }
    [currentDevice beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

}
```

I am pulling my hair out trying to support both orientations on load, with a storyboard app, and without dismissing views after they are viewed (necessary to prevent reloads of UIWebViews). So there are two problems that are just beyond me. Thanks SO.

Comment: It is standard behavior for an app to load in portrait mode, not your fault.

Comment: This might be the way to do this, but I don't do that in my app and I only run in the two landscape modes. I do some of the work in the target configuration (where you pick the orientations) and the rest in the rootViewController. Make sure to support iOS 6 and iOS 5, as they're different.

Comment: I even lock orientation when the accelerometer is on via the rootViewController and it all works, so I wouldn't think about the AppDelegate, myself.

Comment: @RichardAltenburg-Brainchild why is that the case? Is there no way to get around it? Safari for example has no problem opening in landscape mode.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when the app loads in portrait mode? Is it only the splash screen or even when the app is running? The orientation info is received only after the rootViewController is loaded as far as i know.

Comment: @NightCoder the above method is called inside a ViewDidLoad, but always shows portrait the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Advanced App Tricks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) section of the iOS App Programming Guide has some guidelines about `Launching in Landscape Mode`, it could be that your answer lies within those few lines (if at all possible). Especially take care of the `UIInterfaceOrientation` in your `Info.plist` file.